# Python Namespaces in Recursive Functions

Tags: python, recursion, namespaces

My question is relatively simple compared to how I got there. Do recursive functions in Python create a new namespace each time the function calls itself?

I was doing some reading on mergesort and came across this tutorial: https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html#lst-merge

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist)

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I'm understanding the divide-and-conquer well enough, but what I can't get past at the moment is the question I asked above. I can follow the code, but I'm not quite understanding the use of *lefthalf* as the argument that gets passed into the recursive function call of *mergeSort*.

I get that when mergeSort is first called way down at the bottom, alist gets chopped into [54, 26, 93, 17] and [17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]. These are lefthalf and righthalf. Then mergeSort gets called on lefthalf. This is where I get confused. Does the recursive call to mergeSort create a whole new namespace, and is that why the lefthalf that gets passed in doesn't collide with the lefthalf defined within the function?

I know the answer to this is really simple and fundamental, so your patience is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the recursive call to mergeSort create a whole new namespace, [...]?

Yes.

Whenever the Interpreter encounters a call to a function, its creates a *frame object*, which is pushed to a *frame stack*. Each time a frame is created, that frame is given its own private namespace, where each variable in the frame is re-defined.

In your case, each time `mergeSort()` is called, Python creates a new frame object, and pushes it to the frame stack. Each time Python creates a frame from a call to `mergeSort()`, `lefthalf` is re-defined.

With a few well placed calls to `print()`, you can see the value of `lefthalf` at each call to `mergeSort()`:

```
 This is the 1 recursive call to mergeSort()
 lefthalf is:  [54, 26, 93, 17]
 alist is:  [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
  This is the 2 recursive call to mergeSort()
  lefthalf is:  [54, 26]
  alist is:  [54, 26, 93, 17]
   This is the 3 recursive call to mergeSort()
   lefthalf is:  [54]
   alist is:  [54, 26]
    This is the 4 recursive call to mergeSort()
     This is the 5 recursive call to mergeSort()
      This is the 6 recursive call to mergeSort()
      lefthalf is:  [93]
      alist is:  [93, 17]
       This is the 7 recursive call to mergeSort()
        This is the 8 recursive call to mergeSort()
         This is the 9 recursive call to mergeSort()
         lefthalf is:  [77, 31]
         alist is:  [77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
          This is the 10 recursive call to mergeSort()
          lefthalf is:  [77]
          alist is:  [77, 31]
           This is the 11 recursive call to mergeSort()
            This is the 12 recursive call to mergeSort()
             This is the 13 recursive call to mergeSort()
             lefthalf is:  [44]
             alist is:  [44, 55, 20]
              This is the 14 recursive call to mergeSort()
               This is the 15 recursive call to mergeSort()
               lefthalf is:  [55]
               alist is:  [55, 20]
                This is the 16 recursive call to mergeSort()
                 This is the 17 recursive call to mergeSort()
[17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, leaf. I guess I'm ultimately getting tripped up by the difference between mergeSort(alist) and mergeSort(lefthalf). How does alist the parameter relate to lefthalf the argument? Doesn't alist _refer_ to lefthalf, thereby making lefthalf = lefthalf[:mid]? But what you're saying is that since lefthalf on the left of the equal sign is part of the new namespace, they're not referring to the same thing

Comment: @ThomasCho Each time `mergeSort()` is called, `alist` refers to whatever argument is passed in. This means that on each call to `mergeSort()`, `alist` will have a different value. I'll modify my answer to see if I can help clear anymore confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a function call (any function call, not just recursive ones) creates a new namespace. BUT, when given as parameters, objects are passed by reference (in your example, the object is a list).

So, the new namespace get its own copy of this reference but it still refers to the same object as in the calling function, and if you change the content of that object, you will notice the change in the calling function.

Not sure I'm being clear enough. Here is [a nice diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670170/7233423) that may help understanding how this works.

Comment: Thanks xhienne. So when _mergeSort_ runs on _lefthalf_, is it changing the contents of _lefthalf_ that was created right before the function call? I'm referring to the line `lefthalf = alist[:mid]`.

Comment: @ThomasCho Exactly. `alist[:mid]` is a brand new list. It (its reference) is assigned to `lefthalf` and then it (still the ref) is passed to `mergeSort` as `alist`. Note that this `alist` is different than the `alist` in the caller (new namespace: they don't refer to the same object). When you modify `alist` (i.e. `alist[x]=y`) you modify `lefthalf` in the caller. Note that if you did `alist = another_list`, you would not be modifying the former list (`lefthalf`), you would be assigning a new ref (to another object) to `alist`.